# Output from cout or printf in C++ not showing in CodeLite on Windows 7

Tags: c++, output, codelite

Okay, so I have a Windows 7 (64) machine, and I downloaded and installed CodeLite.  Although I use Visual Studio just fine, I was looking for an open source alternative for some instructional materials I am preparing.

Every time I run the program, I get a blank console window that pops up.  There is never any output from the actual code in the window.  I have an associate in another state who experiences the same problem and he's used it for a long time with no problems.  If it's an introduced bug in an incremental build or something, that's a pretty big one.

Simple programs:  the default Hello World program using printf, and also if I modify it to be more "C++" like (using cout, including iostream, etc.) - these appear to compile but do not output anything to the console.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I can't find any settings related to setting the standard output device, which you'd think would be set to the console, but I digress.

Thanks again!

J

**UPDATE:  To reproduce, I just try running the code.  Build-->Run and then select "Build and Execute"**

**UPDATE 2: There is an error apparently in the Build, but it still runs the console.  I suppose I need to install some sort of mingw tool?**

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C mingw32-make.exe -j 8 -e -f  Makefile
'mingw32-make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
====0 errors, 0 warnings==== **
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: If you are running avast antivirus out any other that you add an exception to your projects folder

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I've been coding in C++ for over 15 years, and it's a "Hello World" program, so I'm quite confident that's not the problem.

Comment: the code could not be simpler, so it's not that "It seems you have a problem with your code". I have the same issue, just installed CodeLite, followed the "hello world" tutorial, and even wrote a program with compiler errors, always a 0 errors message and a blank console output. Windows choosing MSVC compiler as explained here
http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/QuickStart

Comment: @PedroVicente, I'm experiencing the same issue here, so how did you solve it?

Comment: I solved it by not using CodeLite.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing but your compiler problem.

Remove your mingw compiler folder from C drive and download TDM GCC compiler for C++ and install the TDM GCC compiler in the same directory of codelite.

Link for downloading the compiler: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens in CodeLite when you download a **Stable Version**.

[CodeLite Stable Version Download Page Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq1ak.png)

What you have to do is, download **Monthly Build** (which is right above the stable version on the download page.

[CodeLite Monthly Build Version Download Page Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6VIm.png)

I mistakenly download the stable version and faced the same issue as you, which i solved by downloading the monthly build.